# Session satus is not set in some page of php

Tags: php, session

I am using Elgg Application, Inside FB connect plugin i am starting Session and setting some variables in the same folder i am accessing this session attributes its working fine..

But i included one more php file, after log-in if i directly call this page through url session_status is 1 but in other two folders its is set...

How to set session here also, their should be any link between pages to session variables

can any one help...

Fb_connect folder

```
str= "var/www/elgg/mod/fb_connect
import-contact-plugin-str="var/www/elgg/mod/importer.
```

new php file i added

```
url=var/www/elgg/engine/sample.php
```

Comment: You have `session_start();` in that file where you trying to access session?

Comment: Start the session like that `session_start();` at the top of `sample.php`

Answer (score 0):

When you work with Elgg, you [shouldn't change its core](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Dont_Modify_Core). Almost everything can be done by plugins, and that's the preferred way of working with Elgg.

Elgg sessions are kept in database and session start is called on system boot event. When you're in plugin context however, the session is already in place, no need to to additional session_start call.

So if you decide to go on modifying the core, you should run your logic from callback registered to boot system:

```
elgg_register_event_handler('boot', 'system', YOUR_CALLBACK);
```